# Dynamic Frame Creation

Tags: javascript, html, frame

I have a web page, normal no fuzz or weird stuff. And I want to trap that page inside an html frame when a user clicks on a given link.

The thing is i don't want to reload the page. Some kind of dynamic DOM trickery seems the way to go, but to no avail in my tests.

If anyone has any ideas it would be great!

Thanks

Comment: need to clarify. it's confusing if these are all your pages / how many pages there are .. where the link and iframe is, and where the target page is

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done without a reload, at least not sanely.

It *may* be possible to move a complete DOM tree into a newly created, empty document within an IFRAME, but yuck! it sounds horribly expensive, will cause any Movies / animations and other things to reload, and you're still stuck with the outside document, where you need to remove all the elements so only the IFRAME or FRAME remains. Then you may encounter browser specific quirks when moving the DOM, and on and on....

I would really go with a reload.

Answer (score 0):

The only other solution I can think of (not tested) is to already have the frame structure, with some of the frames with size 0.
When the user clicks on the link you just resize the frames.

Does this make sense?